# Where can we put a call to stopSelf() or stopService() method of Android to stop the service?

Tags: android, service

I have created one android app in which I am starting a service by calling startService() method. I want to stop the service when the task assigned to it is completed. How can I check that the corresponding task is completed? Can I call stopSelf() in onStartCommand()? What is the best practice to call stopSelf() or stopService() method? Where should the call of it be placed?

Thanks!

Comment: You can open your Android SDK directory, browse to ApiDemos `src/com.example.android.apis.app`, open `AlarmService_Service.java` for more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// main.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center">
<TextView  
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Services Demo" android:gravity="center" android:textSize="20sp" android:padding="20dp"/>
<Button android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/buttonStart" android:text="Start"></Button>
<Button android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Stop" android:id="@+id/buttonStop"></Button>
</LinearLayout>



//Activity class


 public class ServicesDemo extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
  private static final String TAG = "ServicesDemo";
  Button buttonStart, buttonStop;

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    buttonStart = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonStart);
    buttonStop = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonStop);

    buttonStart.setOnClickListener(this);
    buttonStop.setOnClickListener(this);
  }

  public void onClick(View src) {
    switch (src.getId()) {
    case R.id.buttonStart:
      Log.d(TAG, "onClick: starting srvice");
      startService(new Intent(this, MyService.class));
      break;
    case R.id.buttonStop:
      Log.d(TAG, "onClick: stopping srvice");

 stopService(new Intent(this, MyService.class));
      break;
    }
  }
}

//Service class

public class MyService extends Service {
    private static final String TAG = "MyService";
    MediaPlayer player;

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "My Service Bind", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "My Service Created", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate");

        player = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.preview);
        player.setLooping(false); // Set looping
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "My Service Stopped", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Log.d(TAG, "onDestroy");
        player.stop();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startid) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "My Service Started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Log.d(TAG, "onStart");
        player.start();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If would insist better option is to use `IntentService` if you want to perform a particular task and stop the service. By using `IntentService` you are get notified using a `BroadCastReceiver` when your task is completed. [`Here`](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-fundamentals-intentservice-basics/) is a complete explanation with example.